# How to make a Win 32 App run as a Windows Service?

Tags: winapi, windows-services

Our company just completed a Win 32 Application project, and we have a executable program and it works fine in Windows. Now we have to run it as a windows service under Network account. I am pretty new to Windows Service, so please advice, what should I do to transform this program to a Windows Service? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you all for replying, but do I need to make some changes to the source code? For instance, if I have a HelloWorld program which only has a "printf("Hello World\n");", how can I make this program run as a windows service? I cant do this by just use SC create/Start. Thank you.

Comment: Read my answer properly. You need to call RegisterServiceCtrlHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "Win32 Application project" you mean "GUI program", then do **not** run that as a service. Otherwise, here's what you need to do:

- Register a service control handler using [RegisterServiceCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685054%28VS.85%29.aspx) as soon as your program starts. This is required so you can handle the start and stop events. If you do not do this the service manager will kill your process because it thinks it's not a real service.
- If you have an installer, you can use the sc command to create the service. For example: `sc create MyService binPath= "C:\PathToExe\MyService.exe" type= own start= auto`.
- Alternatively you can call [CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you have code to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you want to run your application as a windows service, there is a utility in Windows Resource Kits. It's name is srvany.exe and you can find documentation about it here:
http://search.microsoft.com/search/results.aspx?st=b&View=en-us&s=1&c=0&qu=137890

Srvany.exe can be downloaded as part of Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Srvany.exe is a fine, free solution (as described by alemjerus), but please check out [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) if you are working in a professional environment and need a robust/advanced feature set.

Good luck!